# How to use crawlme npm module

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use crawlme node module in order to make my Ember app crawlable, but the documentation is not enough for me to understand how it works; could someone explain step by step the operations needed to make it work?

I made a crawl.js file using the sample code:

```
var
connect = require('connect'),
http = require('http'),
crawlme = require('crawlme');

var app = connect()
.use(crawlme())
.use(connect.static(__dirname + '/webroot'));

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

and uploaded it in my website's root directory; but i don't know how to customize it, since launching node crawl.js on the server, the command works and the script runs, but the website still not crawlable for google (in webmaster tool, i can see that google is not able to see the inner html of pages)

Comment: You need to have some links in your app that starts with '#!'.  But for me, crawlme makes nodejs crash when it renders the second page.

Comment: Yes, the hashbang implementation was not a problem, but finally now i'm using judo (npm install judo) to generate HTML snapshot via phantomjs